# Windows Server DNS Redirect

Tags: domain-name-system

I would like to redirect a domain to a host on my local network.

For example

www.microsoft.com locally redirects to: host.ad.mydomain.local

What type of DNS record do I need?

Comment: A `CNAME`. But ask on serverfault.com, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need a CNAME record.

But I agree; we should have some easier functionality for moving between the StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

CNAME won't work. You can't even create a CNAME www.microsoft.com pointing to host.yourdomain.local because you are not hosting the domain "microsoft.com".

You can create a subzone called "microsoft.com", then a CNAME called "www" pointing to your own host.yourdomain.local. But then your internal users who use your DNS for name resolution won't be able to resolve other hosts under "microsoft.com" such as "msdn.microsoft.com" as your subzone doesn't have that record. Or you can create a wildcard record "*"  in your subzone "microsoft.com", pointing to yourhost.yourdomain.local, then everything under microsoft.com will be brought to yourhost. This is sort of a DNS hijack, albeit internally only.

With that said, strictly speaking of the example you gave, it's a very interesting setup. Why would you want to re-direct microsoft.com traffic to your own host?